# Class Inheritance for the parent __int__ in Python

Tags: python-3.x, class, inheritance

My code is provided in the end. I want to let the ***class general*** inherit all the variables of the constructor (_ *init* _) in the ***class LDA***. It seems that when the method ***X_F*** in the ***class general*** calls the X_c, it just returns the objective rather than the array of np.random.rand(3,2) generated in the main. I tried to let the method ***X_F*** print the value of the variable ***m***, but the printed result is a default value of 3, rather than 10.

```
class LDA:
      def __init__(self, X_c, m = 3, K=1):
        self.X_c =X_c
        self.m =m
        self.K = K
      def Squared_L2_loss(self):
        X_result = general(self).X_F()
        return X_result

class general(LDA):
     def X_F(self):
        X = self.X_c[0]
        print(self.m)
        return X.T

if __name__ == '__main__':
  X_c=np.random.rand(3,2)
  X = LDA(X_c, m=10, K=30)
```

Comment: Are you sure `return X_result` should be dedented so it's part of `class LDA` instead of part of `Squared_L2_loss`?

Comment: ...indeed, for the reason described above, when I run the code in the question I get a `SyntaxError: 'return' outside function`

Comment: Also, notice how you're creating an `LDA` instead of an instance of `general`?

Comment: Fixing those bugs, as shown at https://ideone.com/nCzqmW, your code no longer exhibits the problem described.